# Having a Syntax error using SQL Server management studio in generating an auto-increment ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone correct this syntax , i cant execute it ,

```
ALTER TABLE Patient 
DROP COLUMN PatientID;
GO
ALTER TABLE Patient 
ADD COLUMN PatientID AS(‘PID-‘+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15));?
```

Comment: use normal apostrophes: `'PID-'`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need apostrophes `' '` :

```
ALTER TABLE Patient 
DROP COLUMN PatientID
GO
ALTER TABLE Patient 
ADD PatientID AS 'PID-' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE Patient
ADD PatientID AS 'PID-' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15))